# Prove by mathematical induction $1+ a + a^2 +a^3+ ...+a^n =\frac {1-a^{n+1}}{1-a\;\;\;}$. a does not equal one

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove by mathematical induction $$1+ a + a^2 +a^3+ ...+a^n =\frac  {1-a^{n+1}}{1-a\;\;\;\;}$$ where  $a \neq1$

When doing the proof, wouldn't this fail the base case since $s(1)$ would make it false?

Comment: Why shouldn't $a$ equal zero? It is $1$ that is the dangerous value for $a$ in this case.

Comment: That is the problem. I know that a is the dangerous value for this case. The problem that has been given to me requires that a not equal zero!

Comment: The expression is correct. Wouldn't using -1 fail the rules of mathematical induction though?

Comment: **Hint** The value of $a$ isn't relevant so long as it's not $1$. Induction is done on $n$.

Comment: Since you think it is false: what _is_ $s(1)$, the base case, in this case? Write it out explicitly, so we can help you understand what you've done wrong.

Comment: If $ n=1$, the formula is true, because $1+a = (1-a^2)/(1-a) $. So there is no problem with the base case.

Comment: Oh I see what I done wrong here. The answer would be 1-a^2/1-a

Comment: Yet another induction exercise that's better done another way. Multiply both sides by $1-a$. That operation is reversible since $a \ne 1$.

Comment: If $n=0$ the formula is true since $1 = \frac{1-a}{1-a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$1+ a + a^2 +a^3+ ...+a^n 
=\frac  {1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
1+ a + a^2 +a^3+ ...+a^n+a^{n+1} 
&=(1+ a + a^2 +a^3+ ...+a^n)+a^{n+1}\\ 
&=\frac  {1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}+a^{n+1}\\
&=\frac  {1-a^{n+1}+(1-a)a^{n+1}}{1-a}\\
&=\frac  {1-a^{n+1}+a^{n+1}-a^{n+2}}{1-a}\\
&=\frac  {1-a^{n+2}}{1-a}\\
\end{array}
$